# Sum from field values and output the result inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did this before with javascript, and have no idea to make it using jquery.

I hope you can help me!

I tried the next:

```
<script>

$('.field').mouseout(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.field').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
      $("#resultado").html(sum.toFixed(2));
});​​​​​​​​​

</script>
```

The div resultado should change the content. Not happening :/

Comment: Have you tried using FireBug or at lease place an `alert` to see which part of the code gets executed, and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the blur event, not the mouseout

```
$('.field').blur(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.field').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#resultado").html(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syJ9g/1/

---

or bind to all kinds of events

```
$('.field').bind("mouseout blur click", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.field').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#resultado").html(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syJ9g/2/